# Toggle Class of a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just getting started with jQuery,I have a form I want to replace checkboxes with with labels that will change color to indicate if checkbox is checked or not. So fat my code is making the label disappear completely and then reappear with same(wrong) class, not just the .off class.

If this is the wrong approach let me know, I am not familiar with best practices, nor design patterns in JS.

Here is the code that I have:

HTML:

```
<label class='off'>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  TEXT
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.off {
    background-color: #E00;
}
.on {
    background-color: #0C0;
}
label > input {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $("label").click( function(){
    $(this).first().toggle( function(){
      $(this).first()
      .removeClass("off")
      .addClass("on");
    }, function(){
      $(this).first()
      .removeClass("on")
      .addClass("off");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [jQuery toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). Just to make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use jQuery, i'd suggest using the following instead:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuy3Lhxc/)

```
$('input:checkbox').off('change').on('change', function(){
    $(this).parent('label').prop('class', this.checked ? 'on' : 'off');
});
```

---

You can also avoid jQuery completely by restructuring the HTML and using the [**`:checked`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo class.

[**Alternative example**](http://jsfiddle.net/epunsmt2/)

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">Text</label>
```

CSS

```
label {
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #E00;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input:checked + label {
    background-color: #0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the label background color responding to whether the checkbox is checked by inspecting the `checked` property of the input itself:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
       var on = this.checked;
       $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('off', !on).toggleClass('on', on);
    });
});
```

- [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9wnn43m/3)

Comment: Note state of the checkbox may change but not by clicking it, listening to `change` event would be better. And I think the checkbox was supposed to be hidden.

Comment: @Oriol: Good point. I've incorporated your suggestion into my answer and jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that CSS only:

```html
<input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="mycheckbox">TEXT</label>
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label{
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #E00;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #0C0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3dtev9q/)